# Django model for ordered list with polymorphic relations

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to figure out the way to implement a Django model for optical/mechanical simulations for photovoltaic modules and glazing units. The simplest real-life representation of the problem looks like this:

| Position | Material |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Glass |
| 2 | EVA foil |
| 3 | Solar cells |
| 4 | EVA foil |
| 5 | PVF |

Here is my idea of the data representation:

The class `PVmodule` class handles has the ForeignKey field referencing its composition like so:

```
class PVmodule(models.Model):

    #---components---#
    composition = models.ForeignKey(ModuleComposition,related_name="composition",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The class `ModuleComposition` is an abstraction of an optical stack (as in the table above) - set of **ordered** materials like glass, gas, coatings and polymers... each represented by **separate** django model. Upon `save()` it handles optical calculations based on the ManyToMany relation with the `StackItem` class and fills in its' remaining fields with data automatically:

```
class ModuleComposition(models.Model):
    self.stack = models.ManyToManyField(StackItem)
```

The `StackItem` class is a representation of a single material on a specific position. It relates via ForeignKey to a table handling the specific material parameters.

```
class StackItem(models.Model):
    self.position = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    self.material = models.ForeignKey( ... )
```

I would like this allows the user to define the module composition step by step or to an already existing module composition for quick evaluation.

However, I cannot get my head around the following issues:

1. `material` field in `StackItem` model should be able to point to different models (polymorphic?). No such behaviour for ForeignKey objects.
2. I need to ensure that for each specific `ModuleComposition` each related `StackItem` has a unique position. However these two are spread across different models.
3. Could all this be achieved in a way that would reasonably fit Django Form (or, preferably ModelForm) and enable registration in DjangoAdmin?

Thanks in advance!